# How should I overload the constructor

Tags: qt, constructor, overloading

I oveloaded a QWidget constructor like this:

The .h file:

```
public:
    LCDRange(QWidget* parent = 0);
    LCDRange(QWidget* parent = 0, const char* text = 0);
```

The .cpp file:

```
LCDRange::LCDRange(QWidget* parent): QWidget(parent){
    init();
    std::cout << "constr 1 called" <<std::endl;
}


LCDRange::LCDRange(QWidget* parent, const char* text): QWidget(parent){
    init();
    setText(text);
    std::cout << "constr 2 called" <<std::endl;
}

    void LCDRange::init(){
//code...
}
```

Then, in my main() function, I called the constructor like this:

```
LCDRange* range1 = new LCDRange(this, "Text 1");
```

or like this:

```
LCDRange* range2 = new LCDRange(this);
```

The problem is that the second one (range2) does not work at all.
The compiler complains:

**main.cpp:26: error: call of overloaded 'LCDRange(MyWidget* const)' is ambiguous

     LCDRange* range2 = new LCDRange(this);

candidates are:

LCDRange::LCDRange(QWidget*, const char*)

LCDRange::LCDRange(QWidget*)

LCDRange::LCDRange(const LCDRange&)**

I don't understand where did the third constructor appeared ...
Why does it say "const" in:

> overloaded 'LCDRange(MyWidget* const)

Comment: the third constructor is the auto-created copy-constructor

Comment: Please show the constructor definition also .. the .h file definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are ambiguous because both can be used without arguments, then you have

```
public:
    LCDRange();
    LCDRange();
```

You can remove the first constructor and just use

```
public:
    LCDRange(QWidget* parent = 0, const char* text = 0);
```

An alternative is typical qt-style with 2 constructors:

```
public:
    explicit LCDRange(QWidget* parent = 0);
    explicit LCDRange(const char* text, QWidget* parent = 0);
```

Now, you have a default constructor and a specialized one for `const char* text`. Furthermore, I added `explicit` to prevent the compiler from implicit conversions. You can read more on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit).

Comment: You mean there are two solutions: either to remove the first constructor OR to change the arguments order.